# BSOD error fffff880009ae7e8

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, bsod

I did a P2V vm and now I got 7B error (I can't find arg fffff880009ae7e8 "0xFFFFF880009AE7E8" anywhere in the internet) .. I tried change registry to load scsi driver LSI and still same error . here is dump debugger: (anyone can help?)

```
Windows 7 Kernel Version 7601 MP (1 procs) Free x64
Built by: 7601.23392.amd64fre.win7sp1_ldr.160317-0600
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`02e1d000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`0305f730
System Uptime: not available

*** Fatal System Error: 0x0000007b
                       (0xFFFFF880009AE7E8,0xFFFFFFFFC0000034,0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000000)

Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)

A fatal system error has occurred.
Debugger entered on first try; Bugcheck callbacks have not been invoked.

A fatal system error has occurred.

Connected to Windows 7 7601 x64 target at (Fri Apr 29 15:41:46.311 2016 (UTC - 3:00)), ptr64 TRUE
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................

Press ctrl-c (cdb, kd, ntsd) or ctrl-break (windbg) to abort symbol loads that take too long.
Run !sym noisy before .reload to track down problems loading symbols.

.........
Loading User Symbols

*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 7B, {fffff880009ae7e8, ffffffffc0000034, 0, 0}

Probably caused by : ntkrnlmp.exe ( nt!PnpBootDeviceWait+136 )

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

nt!DbgBreakPointWithStatus:
fffff800`02e851b0 cc              int     3
0: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE (7b)
During the initialization of the I/O system, it is possible that the driver
for the boot device failed to initialize the device that the system is
attempting to boot from, or it is possible for the file system that is
supposed to read that device to either fail its initialization or to simply
not recognize the data on the boot device as a file system structure that
it recognizes.  In the former case, the argument (#1) is the address of a
Unicode string data structure that is the ARC name of the device from which
the boot was being attempted.  In the latter case, the argument (#1) is the
address of the device object that could not be mounted.
If this is the initial setup of the system, then this error can occur if
the system was installed on an unsupported disk or SCSI controller.  Note
that some controllers are supported only by drivers which are in the Windows
Driver Library (WDL) which requires the user to do a custom install.  See
the Windows Driver Library for more information.
This error can also be caused by the installation of a new SCSI adapter or
disk controller or repartitioning the disk with the system partition.  If
this is the case, on x86 systems the boot.ini file must be edited or on ARC
systems setup must be run.  See the "Advanced Server System Administrator's
User Guide" for information on changing boot.ini.
If the argument is a pointer to an ARC name string, then the format of the
first two (and in this case only) longwords will be:
    USHORT Length;
    USHORT MaximumLength;
    PWSTR Buffer;
That is, the first longword will contain something like 00800020 where 20
is the actual length of the Unicode string, and the next longword will
contain the address of buffer.  This address will be in system space, so
the high order bit will be set.
If the argument is a pointer to a device object, then the format of the first
word will be:
    USHORT Type;
That is, the first word will contain a 0003, where the Type code will ALWAYS
be 0003.
Note that this makes it immediately obvious whether the argument is a pointer
to an ARC name string or a device object, since a Unicode string can never
have an odd number of bytes, and a device object will always have a Type
code of 3.
Arguments:
Arg1: fffff880009ae7e8, Pointer to the device object or Unicode string of ARC name
Arg2: ffffffffc0000034, (reserved)
Arg3: 0000000000000000, (reserved)
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 0

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  7601.23392.amd64fre.win7sp1_ldr.160317-0600

DUMP_TYPE:  0

BUGCHECK_P1: fffff880009ae7e8

BUGCHECK_P2: ffffffffc0000034

BUGCHECK_P3: 0

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

CPU_COUNT: 4

CPU_MHZ: 9bb

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 2a

CPU_STEPPING: 7

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x7B

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  name

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  04-29-2016 15:42:13.0343

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10586.567 amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80002f7e262 to fffff80002e851b0

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`009ae038 fffff800`02f7e262 : fffff880`009ae7e8 fffffa80`03d17230 00000000`00000065 fffff800`02ec8de8 : nt!DbgBreakPointWithStatus
fffff880`009ae040 fffff800`02f7f04e : 00000000`00000003 00000000`00000000 fffff800`02ec9640 00000000`0000007b : nt!KiBugCheckDebugBreak+0x12
fffff880`009ae0a0 fffff800`02e8d484 : 00000000`00000003 fffff800`02e88bd0 00000000`00000010 00000000`00000082 : nt!KeBugCheck2+0x71e
fffff880`009ae770 fffff800`02fa65f6 : 00000000`0000007b fffff880`009ae7e8 ffffffff`c0000034 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx+0x104
fffff880`009ae7b0 fffff800`033c5d14 : 00000000`00000001 ffffffff`80000130 00000000`00000046 fffff8a0`002b28a0 : nt!PnpBootDeviceWait+0x136
fffff880`009ae830 fffff800`033c6601 : fffff8a0`002aef20 fffff800`008287d0 00000000`00000003 ffffffff`800000e4 : nt!IopInitializeBootDrivers+0x624
fffff880`009ae900 fffff800`033c97e0 : 00000000`00000007 00000000`00000010 ffffffff`8000002c fffff800`00812230 : nt!IoInitSystem+0x801
fffff880`009aea00 fffff800`03319af9 : 72657551`744e0434 fffffa80`03d17230 00000000`00000080 fffffa80`03d17720 : nt!Phase1InitializationDiscard+0x1270
fffff880`009aebd0 fffff800`03126476 : 536f4970`614d6d4d 00000000`00000080 45746547`61656857 fffff800`02e7e719 : nt!Phase1Initialization+0x9
fffff880`009aec00 fffff800`02e7e726 : fffff800`0300be80 fffffa80`03d17230 fffff800`03019cc0 00007845`6b636568 : nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x5a
fffff880`009aec40 00000000`00000000 : fffff880`009af000 fffff880`009a9000 fffff880`009ae510 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x16


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  8d761b6962ef35161b44a89ed36794edd5466700

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  5d95d6f456d998a211cc6f664426215d1738d9f7

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  b28610981796779b4ac02f58898fde25728a775c

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt!PnpBootDeviceWait+136
fffff800`02fa65f6 cc              int     3

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  4c8d48cc

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  4

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!PnpBootDeviceWait+136

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  56eb24e6

IMAGE_VERSION:  6.1.7601.23392

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x7B_nt!PnpBootDeviceWait+136

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x7B_nt!PnpBootDeviceWait+136

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  X64_0x7B_nt!PnpBootDeviceWait+136

TARGET_TIME:  2016-04-29T18:41:45.000Z

OSBUILD:  7601

OSSERVICEPACK:  1000

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  272

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 7

OSEDITION:  Windows 7 WinNt (Service Pack 1) TerminalServer SingleUserTS

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2016-03-17 18:43:02

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  160317-0600

BUILDLAB_STR:  win7sp1_ldr

BUILDOSVER_STR:  6.1.7601.23392.amd64fre.win7sp1_ldr.160317-0600

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME: 18b3

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0x7b_nt!pnpbootdevicewait+136

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {853ea7aa-f487-88ef-34ae-bfecaf2f3903}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

0: kd> lm
start             end                 module name
fffff800`00ba3000 fffff800`00bad000   kdcom      (deferred)             
fffff800`02e1d000 fffff800`03404000   nt         (pdb symbols)          C:\WinDbg\Debuggers\x64\sym\ntkrnlmp.pdb\97219F85530548958964A37DC485AF7E2\ntkrnlmp.pdb
fffff800`03404000 fffff800`0344d000   hal        (deferred)             
fffff880`00c00000 fffff880`00c5c000   volmgrx    (deferred)             
fffff880`00c84000 fffff880`00cd3000   mcupdate_GenuineIntel   (deferred)             
fffff880`00cd3000 fffff880`00ce7000   PSHED      (deferred)             
fffff880`00ce7000 fffff880`00d45000   CLFS       (deferred)             
fffff880`00d45000 fffff880`00dba000   CI         (deferred)             
fffff880`00dba000 fffff880`00dfd380   mfewfpk    (deferred)             
fffff880`00e00000 fffff880`00e57000   ACPI       (deferred)             
fffff880`00e57000 fffff880`00e60000   WMILIB     (deferred)             
fffff880`00e60000 fffff880`00e6a000   msisadrv   (deferred)             
fffff880`00e6a000 fffff880`00e9d000   pci        (deferred)             
fffff880`00e9d000 fffff880`00eaa000   vdrvroot   (deferred)             
fffff880`00eaa000 fffff880`00ebf000   partmgr    (deferred)             
fffff880`00ebf000 fffff880`00ec8000   compbatt   (deferred)             
fffff880`00ec8000 fffff880`00ed4000   BATTC      (deferred)             
fffff880`00ed4000 fffff880`00edc000   intelide   (deferred)             
fffff880`00eeb000 fffff880`00fad000   Wdf01000   (deferred)             
fffff880`00fad000 fffff880`00fbd000   WDFLDR     (deferred)             
fffff880`00fbd000 fffff880`00fcd000   PCIIDEX    (deferred)             
fffff880`00fcd000 fffff880`00fe2000   volmgr     (deferred)             
fffff880`00fe2000 fffff880`00ffc000   mountmgr   (deferred)             
fffff880`0102e000 fffff880`01182000   iaStor     (deferred)             
fffff880`01182000 fffff880`0118b000   atapi      (deferred)             
fffff880`0118b000 fffff880`011b5000   ataport    (deferred)             
fffff880`011b5000 fffff880`011d4000   lsi_scsi   (deferred)             
fffff880`01200000 fffff880`0125e000   msrpc      (deferred)             
fffff880`0125e000 fffff880`012d0000   cng        (deferred)             
fffff880`012d3000 fffff880`01337000   storport   (deferred)             
fffff880`01337000 fffff880`01354000   lsi_sas    (deferred)             
fffff880`01354000 fffff880`0135f000   amdxata    (deferred)             
fffff880`0135f000 fffff880`01372000   lsi_sas2   (deferred)             
fffff880`01372000 fffff880`013be000   fltmgr     (deferred)             
fffff880`013be000 fffff880`013d2000   fileinfo   (deferred)             
fffff880`013d2000 fffff880`013fdb00   FirePM     (deferred)             
fffff880`01400000 fffff880`0141b000   ksecdd     (deferred)             
fffff880`0141b000 fffff880`0142c000   pcw        (deferred)             
fffff880`0142c000 fffff880`01436000   Fs_Rec     (deferred)             
fffff880`01444000 fffff880`015ed000   Ntfs       (deferred)             
fffff880`01601000 fffff880`016f4000   ndis       (deferred)             
fffff880`016f4000 fffff880`01754000   NETIO      (deferred)             
fffff880`01754000 fffff880`0177f000   ksecpkg    (deferred)             
fffff880`0177f000 fffff880`017c8000   fwpkclnt   (deferred)             
fffff880`01801000 fffff880`01a00000   tcpip      (deferred)             
fffff880`01a00000 fffff880`01a53000   CCORE64    (deferred)             
fffff880`01a53000 fffff880`01a71000   mup        (deferred)             
fffff880`01aee000 fffff880`01b3a000   volsnap    (deferred)             
fffff880`01b3a000 fffff880`01b43000   stdcfltn   (deferred)             
fffff880`01b43000 fffff880`01b4b000   spldr      (deferred)             
fffff880`01b4b000 fffff880`01b85000   rdyboost   (deferred)             
fffff880`01b85000 fffff880`01bcde80   prot_2k    (deferred)             
fffff880`01cc5000 fffff880`01d5f680   mfehidk    (deferred)             
fffff880`01d60000 fffff880`01d69000   hwpolicy   (deferred)             
fffff880`01d69000 fffff880`01da3000   fvevol     (deferred)             
fffff880`01da3000 fffff880`01db8000   disk       (deferred)             
fffff880`01db8000 fffff880`01de8000   CLASSPNP   (deferred)             
0: kd> !devnode
Dumping IopRootDeviceNode (= 0xfffffa8003d4a710)
DevNode 0xfffffa8003d4a710 for PDO 0xfffffa8003d8ce30
  Parent 0000000000   Sibling 0000000000   Child 0xfffffa8003d512d0   
  InstancePath is "HTREE\ROOT\0"
  State = DeviceNodeStarted (0x308)
  Previous State = DeviceNodeEnumerateCompletion (0x30d)
  StateHistory[06] = DeviceNodeEnumerateCompletion (0x30d)
  StateHistory[05] = DeviceNodeEnumeratePending (0x30c)
  StateHistory[04] = DeviceNodeStarted (0x308)
  StateHistory[03] = DeviceNodeEnumerateCompletion (0x30d)
  StateHistory[02] = DeviceNodeEnumeratePending (0x30c)
  StateHistory[01] = DeviceNodeStarted (0x308)
  StateHistory[00] = DeviceNodeUninitialized (0x301)
  StateHistory[19] = Unknown State (0x0)
  StateHistory[18] = Unknown State (0x0)
  StateHistory[17] = Unknown State (0x0)
  StateHistory[16] = Unknown State (0x0)
  StateHistory[15] = Unknown State (0x0)
  StateHistory[14] = Unknown State (0x0)
  StateHistory[13] = Unknown State (0x0)
  StateHistory[12] = Unknown State (0x0)
  StateHistory[11] = Unknown State (0x0)
  StateHistory[10] = Unknown State (0x0)
  StateHistory[09] = Unknown State (0x0)
  StateHistory[08] = Unknown State (0x0)
  StateHistory[07] = Unknown State (0x0)
  Flags (0x00000131)  DNF_MADEUP, DNF_ENUMERATED, 
                      DNF_IDS_QUERIED, DNF_NO_RESOURCE_REQUIRED
  DisableableDepends = 3 (from children)
0: kd> !devnode 0 1 scsi
Dumping IopRootDeviceNode (= 0xfffffa8003d4a710)
0: kd>  !devnode 0 1 atapi
Dumping IopRootDeviceNode (= 0xfffffa8003d4a710)
```

Comment: Of course you wouldn't find anything, it refers to memory contents local to your PC. Not that it would help, anyway. Please add details about the VM to your question, including at least the VM software and the virtual disk controller. Also, what controller was used on the physical system?

Comment: Hi @Daniel B  thank you for the input.
VMware Workstation Pro 12.0.1 build-3160714
I tried to use SCSI, SATA and IDE and got same results. Right now its setup with SCSI in the VM machine.
Original physical system controller was IDE ATA/ATAPI Intel Mobile Express Chipset SATA AHCI controller.